# How to insert document or fields in nested documents in mongo

Tags: mongodb, perl, mongodb-query

I want collection named systems under which there is a document named sub_systems and under which there are three documents named high mid & low. And each high, mid and low contains separate multiple documents Like below

```
systems: {
           sub_system_1 : {
                            high :{ {task1},
                                    {task2},
                                    .......
                                  },                                
                            mid  :{ {task1},
                                    {task2},
                                    .......
                                  },
                            low :{ {task1},
                                    {task2},
                                    .......
                                  },
                          },
           sub_system_2 : {
                            high :{ {task1},
                                    {task2},
                                    .......
                                  },                                
                            mid  :{ {task1},
                                    {task2},
                                    .......
                                  },
                            low :{ {task1},
                                    {task2},
                                    .......
                                  },
                          },
           ............
         }
```

So following are the questions I'm having
1. How will I create such nested document.
2. How will I insert new sub_system in the systems collection.
3. How will I insert new priority (high, mid, low) under sub_system document.
4. How will I insert new task in a specific sub_system and  under a specific priority(high,low, mid) document

I want to know this using mongo shell and also with perl mongodb

Answer (score 9):

## **Using Shell**

### 1.How will I create such nested document

```
db.systems.insert( [{"name": "sub_system_1", "data" : {"high" :["task1","task2"], "mid": ["task1","task2"], "low" : ["task1","task2"]}},{"name": "sub_system_2" ,"data": {"high" :["task1","task2"], "mid": ["task1","task2"], "low" : ["task1","task2"]}}])
```

### 2.How will I insert new sub_system in the systems collection

```
db.systems.insert( {"name": "sub_system_3", "data" : {"high" :["task1","task2"], "mid": ["task1","task2"], "low" : ["task1","task2"]}})
```

### 3.How will I insert new priority (high, mid, low) under sub_system document

```
// First you need to find the document using the name field
var sub_system_1 = db.systems.findOne({"name":"sub_system_1"})
// set your new priority
sub_system_1.data.new_priority = [ "task1", "task2" ]
// Save updated document 
db.systems.save(sub_system_1)
```

You can also do the update in one statement using the updateOne call please see below documentation 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#db.collection.updateOne

### 4.How will I insert new task in a specific sub_system and under a specific priority(high,low, mid) document

```
// First you need to find the document using the name field
var sub_system_1 = db.systems.findOne({"name":"sub_system_1"})
// Now we add a new task to priority low
sub_system_1.data.low[sub_system_1.data.low.length] = "task3"
// Save updated document 
db.systems.save(sub_system_1)
```

## **Using perl mongodb**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MongoDB::Connection;

my $mongodb_dbhost = 'mongodb.co.za';
my $mongodb_dbname = 'systems_production';
my $mongodb_dbtable = 'systems';

my $connection   =  MongoDB::Connection->new(host => $mongodb_dbhost);

my $collection = $connection->$mongodb_dbname->$mongodb_dbtable;
```

### 1. How will I create such nested document

```
my $data = $collection->insert( [
    {
       "name": "sub_system_1", "data" : {"high" :["task1","task2"], "mid":     ["task1","task2"], "low" : ["task1","task2"]}
},
{
    "name": "sub_system_2" ,"data": {"high" :["task1","task2"], "mid":    ["task1","task2"], "low" : ["task1","task2"]}
}
  ]);
```

### 2. How will I insert new sub_system in the systems collection

```
  $data = $collection->insert({
      "name": "sub_system_3", 
   "data" : {"high" :["task1","task2"], "mid": ["task1","task2"], "low" :     ["task1","task2"]}
  });
```

### 3. How will I insert new priority (high, mid, low) under sub_system document

```
my $sub_system_1 = $connection->$mongodb_dbname->$mongodb_dbtable->find_one({'name' => 'sub_system_1'});
$sub_system_1->{data}->{new_priority} = [ "task1", "task2" ];
$collection->save($sub_system_1);
```

### 4. How will I insert new task in a specific sub_system and under a specific priority(high,low, mid) document

```
my $sub_system_1 = $connection->$mongodb_dbname->$mongodb_dbtable->find_one({'name' => 'sub_system_1'});
 $sub_system_1->{data}->{low}->[scalar(@$sub_system_1->{data}->{low})] = "task3";
 $collection->save($sub_system_1);
```

Comment: you created array inside high,mid and low and not a document which is totally opposite to what I asked for

Comment: Hi there, looking at your example you cant have a list of task hashes without keys, the tasks would need to be the keys to what ever values you would want to allocate e.g `db.systems.insert( {"name": "sub_system_3", "data" : {"high" :{"task1": "some value","task2": "some other value"}, "mid": {"task1": "some value","task2": "some other value"}, "low" : {"task1": "some value","task2": "some other value"}}})`